# creating the task with the requited fields using Rally Rest api in java

Tags: rally

While creating a user story using Rally rest api, am getting "Validation error: HierarchicalRequirement.Story Type should not be null". I found that there is one required field that I have to pass while creating the story.. but am not sure what attribute I have to use to set it.
Here is my code

```
JsonObject newDefect = new JsonObject();
    newDefect.addProperty("Name", "Under my story");
    newDefect.addProperty("Project", "/project/51356840");
    CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("hierarchicalrequirement", newDefect);
    CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have a required custom field called Story Type in the specified project.  You may have to follow up with your administrator for more details, or browse to an existing story to see what the valid values are for that field.  Once you have that data you should be able to just do something like this:

```
newDefect.addProperty("c_StoryType", "Foo");
```

Comment: Yes that worked!!!! But how do i know what are the attributes that a defect or a story can have? I mean, i was using StoryType instead of c_StoryType

Comment: All custom fields start with a c_ prefix so they don't collide with any built-in field names.  The easiest way to see all the fields is to go to the interactive WSAPI docs and browse through the types on the left: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/